# python cffi parsing error when defining a struct

Tags: python, python-cffi

I am trying to use `python-cffi` to wrap C code. The following `example_build.py` shows an attempt to wrap `lstat()` call:

```
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.set_source("_cstat",
        """
        #include <sys/types.h>
        #include <sys/stat.h>
        #include <unistd.h>
        """,
        libraries=[])

ffi.cdef("""
        struct stat {
            mode_t  st_mode;
            off_t   st_size;
            ...;
        };
        int lstat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ffi.compile()
```

When compile `python example_build.py` will complain that parsing error for `mode_t st_mode`.

```
cffi.api.CDefError: cannot parse "mode_t  st_mode;"
:4:13: before: mode_t
```

A similar example given from the [manual](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#real-example-api-level-out-of-line) doesn't have any problems though. What am I missing? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inform CFFI that `mode_t` and `off_t` are some integer types.  The easiest way is to add these lines first in the cdef():

```c
typedef int... mode_t;   /* means "mode_t is some integer type" */
typedef int... off_t;
```

Comment: real type width may differ. PLEASE DO NOT DEFINE JUST TO INT

Comment: @socketpair: no, the point of the syntax `typedef int... off_t;`, with the ellipsis, is precisely to ask CFFI to find the real type width for you.  It doesn't mean "use exactly int".